# OmniGraffle with LaTex reference

Tags: pdf

Is it possible to **reference a LaTeX label in Omnigraffle**, so that if the OmniGraffle document is included in a LaTex document (as PDF) it links to that section/object?

Example label:

```
\label{sec:introduction}
```

Example reference:

```
\ref{sec:introduction}
```

Example OmniGraffle file:

[image]

Comment: I doubt that LaTeX will be able to look into (and change) an included PDF file/drawing. But let's see whether somebody has an answer. Otherwise please *flag* the post for mod attention and we can try to migrate the question to the TeX site (please do *not* crosspost it yourself).

Comment: Maybe if you went from OmniGraffle to SVG to TikZ. But that sounds like a lot of hassle to me.